# Comparing all rows in a column with all other rows in same column (special query)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In this query, I am given a data frame with a column of 5d euclidean points (stored as an array of doubles). I need to find all the average distances available. That is, for each point a, I calculate the distance to each other point b in the dataframe and find the average of those distances. Please note that I don't want any mathematical approaches or simplifications to this question. The dataframe has two columns, unique_id and vector.

I could do the query, but only with respect to 1 point the following way. The UDF distance calculates the distance between a stored array (ie wrapped array) and a given array. However, it is clear that this approach only works for one point. Also, I tried passing a dataset to a static function. but every time I do that I get an "Invalid Tree: null", that is, the object becomes null as soon as it enters the function ... Finally, I thought of making a UDAF, but I realized that this is not a proper aggregate function. Any help on this would be appreciated !

(Note: this code is in java, but it shouldn't be too different from other languages)

```java
        long equal = 2;
        WrappedArray<Double> num = (WrappedArray<Double> spo.select("vectors")
       .filter(col("unique_id").equalTo(equal)).first().get(0);
        List<Double> frameList =  scala.collection.JavaConverters.seqAsJavaList(num);

        double[] array_answer = frameList.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).toArray();
        UserDefinedFunction compare = udf(
                (WrappedArray<Double> array)  -> cosine_distance(array, array_answer),  DataTypes.DoubleType
        );
        double answer = (double) spo.select("vectors").filter(col("unique_id").notEqual(equal))
            .withColumn("calc", compare.apply(col("vectors")))
            .select(avg("calc")).first().get(0);
        System.out.println(answer);
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using `crossJoin`. Here is 1d (pseudo) code in scala:

```
val df = Seq(("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c", 3)).toDF("unique_id", "vector")

df.select($"unique_id" as "id0", $"vector" as "vector0")
  .crossJoin(df.select($"unique_id" as "id1", $"vector" as "vector1"))
  .filter($"id0" =!= $"id1")
  .groupBy($"id0" as "unique_id")
  .agg(avg(
    abs($"vector0" - $"vector1") /*  use actual distance here */ ) as "mean_distance")
  .show()
```

```
+---------+-------------+
|unique_id|mean_distance|
+---------+-------------+
|        c|          1.5|
|        b|          1.0|
|        a|          1.5|
+---------+-------------+
```